# Retrieve always latest messages from Kafka on reconnection

Tags: c++, apache-kafka, librdkafka

I'm writing a piece of code that needs to read hundreds of messages from Kafka each few milliseconds. I'm using C++ and librdkafka. When my program stops and then restarts it does not need to recover all lost messages since it was stopped, but instead it needs to always read from **latest** messages sent.

As far as I know I can manage consumer offsets by playing with `enable.auto.commit` and `auto.offset.reset`. But, the latter one is only useful when there are no committed offsets while the former one instead let me manage myself the offsets to store.

Playing with these two values I found that if I set `enable.auto.commit` to `false`, without committing any offset, and `auto.offset.reset` to `latest` it seems to retrieve always the latest messages; but how clean is this solution?

My fear is that if between two consumer polls there are 2 messages sent than my consumer only takes the latest, or if no messages where sent it continually reads the same. Both are unwanted behaviour.

Another idea was to clear consumer group offsets or seeking forward, but the `seek` method in librdkafka seems to not work as needed and I cannot find methods to manage consumer groups..

How can I always read latest messages from Kafka using librdkafka?

Comment: seek method is what you need. What issues are you having with it?

Comment: Alternatively, since you seem not to care about keeping track of your previously consumed offset, why are you committing anything? If you disable auto commits and don't commit while consuming, then `auto.offset.reset=latest` will do exactly what you want upon restarts

Comment: @OneCricketeer if I disable auto commits I will always get the latest, but what happens if between two consumer polls are produced 2 messages? I will get both of them or only the latest? I need to retrieve all messages sent on kafka when my process is up, but i don't care of those messages sent when my process is down

Comment: The app will start at the latest offset and read every single message sent thereafter. It doesn't _always_ read the latest message. Feel free to try for yourself

Comment: @tfwatt have u tried the above mentioned approach by OneCricketeer ? Did it worked ?

Comment: @PrateekJoshi disabling auto-commits and `auto.offset.reset=latest` should work, but I do need to read all messages from kafka. It also may generate problems with multiple consumers, since you have no track of where anyone has arrived

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I solved by managing myself the callback on rebalance. This callback will be always executed when a new consumer join or leave the group.

> The rebalance callback is responsible for updating librdkafka's assignment set based on the two events: RdKafka::ERR__ASSIGN_PARTITIONS and RdKafka::ERR__REVOKE_PARTITIONS.

So within the rebalance callback I iterate over the `TopicPartition`s in order to assign them to the consumer, using the latest offsets. The snippet of code is this:

```cpp
class SeekEndRebalanceCb : public RdKafka::RebalanceCb {
  public:
  void rebalance_cb (RdKafka::KafkaConsumer *consumer, RdKafka::ErrorCode err, std::vector<RdKafka::TopicPartition*> &partitions) {
    if (err == RdKafka::ERR__ASSIGN_PARTITIONS) {
      for (auto partition = partitions.begin(); partition != partitions.end(); partition++) {
        (*partition)->set_offset(RdKafka::Topic::OFFSET_END);
      }
      consumer->assign(partitions);
    } else if (err == RdKafka::ERR__REVOKE_PARTITIONS) {
      consumer->unassign();
    } else {
      std::cerr << "Rebalancing error: " << RdKafka::err2str(err) << std::endl;
    }
  }
};
```

In order to use that callback I will set it to the consumer.

```cpp
SeekEndRebalanceCb ex_rb_cb;
if (consumer->set("rebalance_cb", &ex_rb_cb, errstr) != RdKafka::Conf::CONF_OK) {
  std::cerr << errstr << std::endl;
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The consumer->assign(partitions) should be invoked after the end of cycle for

```
class SeekEndRebalanceCb : public RdKafka::RebalanceCb {
  public:
  void rebalance_cb (RdKafka::KafkaConsumer *consumer, RdKafka::ErrorCode err, std::vector<RdKafka::TopicPartition*> &partitions) {
    if (err == RdKafka::ERR__ASSIGN_PARTITIONS) {
       for (auto partition = partitions.begin(); partition != partitions.end(); partition++) 
           (*partition)->set_offset(RdKafka::Topic::OFFSET_END);
       consumer->assign(partitions);
    } else if (err == RdKafka::ERR__REVOKE_PARTITIONS) {
      consumer->unassign();
    } else {
      std::cerr << "Rebalancing error: " << RdKafka::err2str(err) << std::endl;
    }
  }
};
```